# MongoDB, modifydate of data files not updated (Windows)

Tags: mongodb

I just noticed something strange with MongoDb physical files on Windows.
When i update/insert data in my MongoDB database, the modify date of the related *.0 files in 'data' folder is not updated.

I understand that the size is pre-allocated so it stays the same, but why the modify date is not at least updated ?

This is quite an issue for me cause i store the mongo files in Google drive, so nothing is updated due to this weird behavior.

Does anyone have an explanation ?
Thank you

Comment: This is really a question for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as StackExchange is for "programming topics" only. If you read your own question carefully though, you basically answered it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of dba.stackexchange.com , for the next time.

Comment: The two hints here are "close your question and post elsewhere" as it is not appropriate for here. And secondly that you really did answer it yourself. Pre-allocated files don't necessarily "grow" with each modification. Please close your question, if you really still need to ask then ask it elsewhere. Leaving it here for others to clean up and remove is not nice when you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to my own question, i came with the solution of using **mongodump** to keep my data up to date on Google Drive.

I scheduled a task to dump frequently my mongo database into same data folder, so this folder is backed up, it just need some extra work using **mongorestore** on other machines but it's quite easy steps.